# what are the differences between addEventListener('load') and .complete property on the img tag

Tags: javascript, html

why would I use on or the other . 
attaching a `load` event vs checking the `complete` property

```
var img1 = document.querySelector('.img-1');

function loaded() {
  // img loading 
}

if (img1.complete) {
  loaded();
}
```

or

```
var img1 = document.querySelector('.img-1');

img1.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // woo yey image loaded
});
```

Comment: They are complete different things, only linked by the fact that when the load event fires, the complete property is set to true. Note that it is also true for the error event.

Comment: Also you would have to continually poll the `img1.complete` property to know when it was true

Comment: so when would I use `.complete` over `load` event ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The complete property returns whether or not the browser is finished loading an image.

If the image is finished loading, the complete property returns true. If the image is not finished loading, this property returns false.

in this case both of them are doing the same thing but it is possible that events happen before we start listening to them so a work around would be

```
var img1 = document.querySelector('.img-1');

function loaded() {
  // img has loaded 
}

if (img1.complete) {
  loaded();
}
else {
  img1.addEventListener('load', loaded);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

They are strictly different :

`complete` property only says whether the browser is still fetching data or not.
Whenever it gets a response, it will set the `complete` property to `true`, without letting you know if it was a success or a failure.

The `load` event is an `Event` which will fire only when the browser has successfully fetched the resource (in chrome it even fires only when the image has been processed, not in FF).

**You can't replace the `load` event with the `complete` property only.**
If you want to know if an image has been loaded, without resorting to the `load` event (e.g because the image has been declared in HTML markup), you'll also have to check if the image has a value in its `imageWidth` property.

An other solution in this case, is to simply attach your event listener, then set the image's `src` to the same value again. If the image was already loaded, it will be fetched from the cache only, and if it wasn't yet, no new request will happen.

```js
var broken = document.getElementById('broken');
var valid = document.getElementById('valid');

// when the window' load event fires, all resources declared in HTML will be either loaded, either broken.

window.onload = function(){
  console.log('broken complete :', broken.complete);
  console.log('broken loaded :', !!(broken.complete && broken.naturalWidth));
  console.log('valid loaded :', !!(valid.complete && valid.naturalWidth));
  // so it's too late to attach a load event
  
  valid.onload = function(){console.log('loaded again');};
  // except if we force it to fire again
  valid.src = valid.src;
  };
```

```html
<img id="broken" src="http://fakeserver.co/brokenImage.png">
<img id="valid" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png">
```